# MDX Query Via Openquery Does Not Return Expected Data

Tags: ssas, mdx

Need a better question title but here goes. We have a set of queries we are calling from SQL Server (2012) that use data from an OLAP cube. We pull this data in via an `OPENQUERY` call:

```
SELECT "[Time Period].[Month Full Code].[Month Full Code].[MEMBER_CAPTION]" AS timestring
FROM openquery([SSAS_cube],'
    SELECT { } ON 0,
    NONEMPTY ({
        DESCENDANTS({[Time Period].[Month Full Code].[Month Full Code]})
    }) ON 1
    FROM [thecube]
    WHERE (
        [Geography].[Geo County Area].&[1204000057]
    );
')
```

This is returning no data. However, if we run the MDX directly on the SSAS server we do get data:

```
SELECT { } ON 0,
NONEMPTY ({
    DESCENDANTS({[Time Period].[Month Full Code].[Month Full Code]})
}) ON 1
FROM [thecube]
WHERE (
    [Geography].[Geo County Area].&[1204000057]
);
```

This result set is a single column of available times that had data for the give area (with other parameters optional). I think the issue is that there is no column "header" on the MDX result but even doing a simple `SELECT * FROM openquery(...)` returns no data. How can I get this data to return via openquery call?

Comment: An alternative to OPENQUERY is this : https://olapextensions.codeplex.com/ we never use OPENQUERY nowadays as the simplicity and performance of this addin is so much better I can't recommend it highly enough. When we upgraded to sql-server 2016 this project had also been updated so it is supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a function of the flattening that takes place when your MDX query result is flattened into a table for return through the linked server. SSMS uses a CellSet object rather than a table when displaying the query results so it is more flexible.

Please ensure you have something on columns and it should work fine through the linked server.

```
SELECT { [Measures].CurrentMember } ON 0,
NONEMPTY ({
    DESCENDANTS({[Time Period].[Month Full Code].[Month Full Code]})
}) ON 1
FROM [thecube]
WHERE (
    [Geography].[Geo County Area].&[1204000057]
);
```